# Random Walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

So I thought I'd try to find the expectation of $\frac{X_n}{n}$. Let $q=1-p$

I did this by conditioning on the first jump using the law of total of probability with expectations. Before that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_n}{n}]=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[X_n]$.

$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_1=1]+\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_1=-1]$

$=p(\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]+1)+q(\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]-1)$

$=(p+q)\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]+(p-q)$

$=\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]+(2p-1)$

since $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]+(2p-1)$, we use this recursive formula to get

$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_0]+n(2p-1)$

$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=n(2p-1)$

and so 
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_n}{n}]=(2p-1)$

so if $\frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow \mu$ almost surely as the question asks then I think the $\mu$ will have to be $2p-1$ since the expected value of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ would be $\mu$ in that case. My problem is the other way around is not true. You could have A sequence of standard normally distributed random variables $N(0,1)$:

$\{Z_1,Z_2,...\}$ Their expectation is $0$ but they certainly don't tend almost surely to $0$.
I thought I would try thinking about using expectations because I didn't know where to begin and the proof of the Strong Law of Large Numbers uses expectations to show that $\frac{Sn}{n}$ tends almost surely to $\mu$

I also am clueless about the last bit about transience and recurrence

I would love some hints thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You can write $X_{n}=Y_{1}+\cdots+Y_{n}$ where the $Y_{i}$ are iid
with $P\left\{ Y_{1}=1\right\} =p$ and $P\left\{ Y_{1}=-1\right\} =1-p$.

This makes it easier to find $\mu$ (linearity of expectation) and allows application of the strong law of large numbers.

Comment: Fantastic :) I will try to remember this trick

Comment: Try to?? No, that  is not acceptable. You must!!! :-)